# How are Predicate Encryption algorithms implemented?

Tags: algorithm-design, predicate-encryption

After a lot of reading on the internet, i can't seem to figure out how `Predicate Encryption` works.

As i read, it consists of 4 algorithms:

`Setup()` - (outputs `MSK` - Master Secret Key and `PK` - Public Key)

`Encrypt(PK, text)` - (outputs `CT` - ciphertext)

`GenKey(MSK, predicate)` - (outputs a `Token`)

`Query(Token, CT)` - 0 if `false`, 1 if `true`

I don't understand how the `GenKey` algorithm works, how u generate a token based on `MSK` and `predicate`, and of course, how you query the `ciphertext` using the generated `token`.

Can someone point me in the right direction ? Maybe some pseudo-code or very detailed explanation.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the schemes. What scheme do you consider? Or, do you want a pointer to concrete schemes?

Comment: i want a simple scheme, and a practical explanation for its implementation. I would really apreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, your syntax (Setup,GenKey,Encrypt,Query) seems to be the syntax of public-key encryption with keyword-search (PKES). In the case of predicate-based encryption, we use Decrypt rather than Query.

## The Sahai-Waters Fuzzy IBE

I recommend [Sahai and Waters: Fuzzy identity-based encryption (EUROCRYPT 2005)](http://eprint.iacr.org/2004/086) as a first step. I assume you know the basic of pairing-based cryptography and secret sharing.

In Fuzzy IBE, a ciphertext and secret key is associated with attributes sets, $X$ and $Y$, respectively. If $X$ and $Y$ shares at least $t$ elements, one can decrypt the  ciphertext $c_X$ using $sk_Y$.
The syntax is as follows:

- $\mathsf{Setup}(1^{\kappa},n,t)$ outputs $msk$ and $pk$, where $\kappa$ is the security parameter, $n$ is the size of universe, and $t$ is a threshold parameter.
- $\mathsf{GenKey}(msk,Y)$ outputs $sk_Y$, where $Y \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$.
- $\mathsf{Encrypt}(pk,X,m)$ outputs a ciphertxt $c_X$, where $X \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$.
- $\mathsf{Dec}(sk_Y,c_X)$ outputs $m$ if $X$ and $Y$ share at least $t$ elements.

They design the scheme as follows (I omit enc and dec):

- Setup: the master secret key is $\alpha,t_1,\dots,t_n \in \mathbb{Z}_q$ and the master public key is $e(g,g)^{\alpha}$ and $T_i = g^{t_i}$.
- GenKey: The master generates shares $s_1,\dots,s_n$ of $\alpha$ by using $(n,t)$ secret sharing scheme, computes $D_i = g^{s_i/t_i}$ for each $i$, and returns $D_i$ for $i \in Y$.

## Other schemes

Predicate-based encryption schemes based on the paring groups often employ this structure. Intuitively speaking, they hide/share the master secret into user secret keys as Sahai and Waters did.

If you need examples of implementations, we can find (proof-of-concept) implementations of more complex predicate-based encryption schemes in cryptographic libraries:

- [PBC](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/) and [jPBC](http://gas.dia.unisa.it/projects/jpbc/)
- [Charm](http://www.charm-crypto.com/Main.html)